# Spark window function aggregate by most frequent value in row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I want to get the most frequent occurring String in a row,in a given window, and have this value in a new row. (am using Pyspark)

This is what my table looks like.

```
window    label    value
123         a        54
123         a        45
123         a        21
123         b        99
123         b        78
```

I'm doing some aggregation, and at the moment I'm grouping by both `window` and `label`.

```
sqlContext.sql(SELECT avg(value) as avgValue FROM table GROUP BY window, label)
```

This returns the average where window = 123 and label = a and the average where window = 123 and label = b

What I am trying to do, is order `label` by most frequently occurring string descending , so then in my sql statement I can do `SELECT first(label) as majLabel, avg(value) as avgValue FROM table GROUP BY window`

I'm trying to do this in a window function but am just not quite getting there.

```
group = ["window"]

w = (Window().partitionBy(*group))
```

Comment: @zero323 this seems like something you would know how to approach? Given your expertise with Spark's window functions :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['123','a','54'],['123','a','45'],['123','a','21'],['123','b','99'],['123','b','78'],],['window','label','value'])
```

Define a right WindowSpec.

```
win_spec = window.partitionBy(['window','label']).orderBy(col('value').desc())
```

Returns a sequential number starting at 1 within a window partition ['window','label'].

```
str_rank = df.withColumn('string_rank',row_number().over(win_spec))
str_rank.show()
```

This is how the df looks now:

[image]

Select the window with "string_rank" == 1.

```
str_rank.where(col('string_rank')==1).drop('string_rank').show()
```

[image]